# C# chart Datetime to Date

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a Chart that is bound to a "BindingSource". 
I use the Date column from the binding source as the X axis like so:

```
chart1.Series["chart"].XValueMember = "Date");
```

My problem on the other hand is that it also takes the hours/minutes/seconds in to account. (So instead of grouping the entire day to one bar it makes several bars for one day)

Is there a way to make sure that the hours/minute/seconds are ignored in the chart and just grouped together for each day? Without having to change the data source (Seeing the seconds and stuff are important for the datagridview that uses the same data source)  (And while at it, is it also possible to do that for months/years?)

Full code for the chart:

```
BindingSource Datasource= new BindingSource();
Datasource.DataSource = Selected_DataTables;
        chart1.Series.Clear();
        chart1.Series.Add("chart");
        chart1.Series["chart"].XValueMember = "Date";
        chart1.Series["chart"].YValueMembers = "Sales";
        chart1.DataSource = Datasource;
        chart1.DataBind();
```

("Selected_DataTables" being a collection of optional database query results)

Comment: Can't you just fix the data to group by date?

Comment: I think that it is better to create something like ViewModel and convert your data in a way you want it to look in the report. In order to get date without hours / minutes / seconds, you can simply get `Date` property of your date column.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev What is the syntax for that concerning databound to a chart.

Comment: @DavidG  That's what i want to do, but i do not know how to do that for the Chart. And after an age of googling all i can find are pages that only change the label :|

Comment: I meant to group the data *before* you give it to the chart.

Comment: @A.Bakker Could you provide more code on how and where you bind your data?

Comment: @DavidG Maybe i'm thinking to difficult but the data is bound to a source...so how can i group it without effecting the original data (Seeing that data does require the hours/seconds for something else)?

Comment: What is `Datasource` specifically in this case? :)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Added all the code ther is to it concerning the chart. The Datasource is just a BindingSource Datasource= new BindingSource(); filled with data from a datatable

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev i think i mentioned everything there is to it (except for the data the fills the data tables but that doesn't seem relevant to this)

Comment: @A.Bakker - Please provide the code for the data that fills the `DataTable`. It's the only code that is relevant.

Comment: @Enigmativity how is that relevant?
It is just simply a Datatable containing data from several SQL queries that are mushed together... The data itself is fine..all i need is to know how a datetime  column can be treated as a date only column by a chart

Comment: Made myself a solution that works. Thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: @A.Bakker - Your input data contains the time component so it would just be simpler to convert the input to have only a date component. I don't want to rewrite the code to demonstrate - that's your job. Your answer demonstrates how it can be done, but we couldn't provide that answer because we didn't have your input data. Hence it is relevant.

Comment: @EnigmativityAs i mentioned before, i can not change the original input data to date format because the data that comes in does need the timestamps for other things then the chart. That's why i chose to just copy the data and remove it in the copy and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution was to make a copy of the original Datatable and make that copy my datasource for the Graph. The copy has no effect on the original so i was able to use the code below to convert it to the format i wanted. Hope it helps somebody.

```
    DataTable chart_DateTable = new DataTable();
    chart_DateTable = Selected_DataTables.Copy();


    foreach (DataRow row in chart_DateTable.Rows)
    {

        DateTime test2 = DateTime.Parse(row["Datum"].ToString());
        row["Datum"] = test2.Date;
    }
```